# PHP - Obtain last row in CouchDB

Tags: php, database, nosql, couchdb

I am trying to find a method of obtaining the last row in CouchDB using PHP. I have searched around, and I have not found very much that is helpful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't PHP specific per se, but this sounds like a job for the CouchDB descending and limit params:

```
$ curl -X GET 'http://localhost:5984/test2/_design/test_views/_view/view1'
{"total_rows":4,"offset":0,"rows":[
{"id":"test1","key":["account1","2009-05-13T11:59:22.281Z"],"value":{"rel":"account1"}},
{"id":"test2","key":["account2","2012-05-13T11:59:22.281Z"],"value":{"rel":"account2"}},
{"id":"test3","key":["account3","2011-05-13T11:59:22.281Z"],"value":{"rel":"account3"}},
{"id":"test4","key":["account4","2010-05-13T11:59:22.281Z"],"value":{"rel":"account4"}}
]}

$ curl -X GET 'http://localhost:5984/test2/_design/test_views/_view/view1?descending=true&limit=1'
{"total_rows":4,"offset":0,"rows":[
{"id":"test4","key":["account4","2010-05-13T11:59:22.281Z"],"value":{"rel":"account4"}}
]}
```

Descending reverses the order, limit stops after n results (see reference [here](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/HTTP_view_API#Querying_Options)).